# unblock-file can get rid of prompt warning when try to run ps1 file from internet machine

Tags: powershell

i want to rename photos based on exif data on my remote machine, the code is as follows:

```
Unblock-File -path ..\exif-datetaken.ps1

Get-ChildItem *.jpg | foreach {
#Write-Host "$_`t->`t" -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewLine 
$date = (..\exif-datetaken.ps1 $_.FullName)
if ($date -eq $null) {
    Write-Host '{ No ''Date Taken'' in Exif }' -ForegroundColor Cyan    
    return
}
$newName = $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss') + $_.extension
$newName = (Join-Path $_.DirectoryName $newName)
Write-Host $newName -ForegroundColor Cyan
mv $_ $newName
}
```

i use unblock-file to get rid of warning, as i need to click on button to confirm for each photo manually, 
but i found unblock-file do not work, i still get that warning prompt,

is it the wrong way to do to resolve this problem ?

Comment: what warning? [*grin*] some details would likely help a bit ...

Comment: just run the program you trusted.........., confirm to run \\x.x.x.x\photo\exif-datetaken.ps1 ? do not run(D), run once(R), suspend(S), i need to press R for each photo, and i also set-executionpolicy unrestricted, but do not work,

Comment: This is just a guess, but it might be possible that since the powershell script exists on a remote machine and assuming this ip/host is not in your trusted internet zones, it will always be considered untrustworthy. Unrestricted is designed to prompt in cases like these. If you are certain you trust this file, maybe try `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any file you download from the web will have ADS (alternate date stream) attached which indicates that it came form the web, and should not be trusted.

You have to use Unblock-File to get rid of that ADS.

If you are doing this for lots of downloaded files, then you have to do that to all of them before take any other actions on them.

```
ForEach ($TargetPath in $TargetPaths)
{
    $TargetPath
    Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetPath -Recurse | Unblock-File
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

# Your rename code here
```

If you are running into prompts, after any downloaded file, then you may need to implement the -Confirm or -Force switch as where prudent.

```
Unblock-File -Confirm:$false
Rename-Item -Confirm:$false
```

Unblock is really only needed for downloaded files.
If you are getting other prompts the some lock is on the file or a permission issue. Yet, since you are not showing the error, we are left to guess.

Comment: i created file exif-datetaken.ps1, and uploaded to remote machine, then i cd to that remote machine, and run command line code to call that ps1 file, and then i get no-trust warning, need me to manually confirm,

Comment: i set set-executionpolicy bypass, and now there is no warning

Comment: Yeppers, that executionpolicy must be set for scripts to run period, well, you could run them in the ISE or VSCode using select all and run selection, but that is a interactive thing only. By default it's set to restricted, and for normal operations should be set to RemoteSigned to allow you to run local scripts. There are little reason to go higher than that level, though you'll see statements, and some docs to use Unrestricted. If you do, you should limit that to your session (process or user). Lots of docs on this setting.